# Auto scaling website while scaling browser window

Tags: javascript, jquery, resize

I have a website with kinda large images which fits nicely in a 1920/1080 window, but not smaller windows. Even different browsers show me some other stuff. I Googled a lot, but couldn't find exactly what I need!

Here I have an example:  http://www.serialcut.com/

This is exactly what I need.

This must be done with any kind of jQuery or JavaScript.

Can somebody give me some code to do this?

Comment: It's called "Responsive" design, usually most of it is CSS, but there are neat ways using bootstrap or jQuery

Comment: Please include screenshots of both the actual results and the desired results, and a [Minimal, Complete, Tested and Readable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) reproducing your problem ([JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/)?, of which the code should also be pasted in the question), rather than a vague description and a link.

Answer (score 0):

You could use **CSS3** *transforms* and *media queries*.

http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-transforms/
http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-mediaqueries/

Your page will then be resize according to the rules set by media queries at your css stylesheet:

```css
@media screen and (min-width:1200px) {

    #container {

        width:1100px;

    }  

    header h1#logo a {

        width:1100px;
        height:150px;
        background:url(image.jpg) no-repeat 0 0;

    }                          

}
```

You may also scale,rotate,move,etc any element from your page by setting its transformation properties:

```css
div {

  transform: scale(2) rotate(45deg);
  transform: scale(2) rotate3d(0, 0, 1, 45deg);

}
```

You can access this properties through pure javascript code if you want to:

```js
document.querySelector('div').style.webkitTransform="scale(3)";
```